# A minor confusion in digitalWrite command

Tags: digitalwrite

Will the Arduino IDE interpret digitalWrite(13,x), where x>0, as digitalWrite(13,HIGH)?
And will it interpret digitalWrite(13,x), where x<=0, as digitalWrite(13,LOW)?

Comment: 0 is low, everything else is HIGH

Comment: but some joker could make an arduino core where LOW is defined as 2. the AVR code for digitalWrite and digitalRead would work. it doesn't assume that LOW is 0. so your code shouldn't do that either. (but in my sketches I often assume that LOW is 0).

Comment: the esp8266 core digitalRead and digitalWrite functions ignore LOW and HIGH  and use `if (val)` and return the state of the register bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every other value than `0` or `LOW` will result in setting the pin to `HIGH`. In the following I explain why:

The function `digitalWrite()` can be seen in the file `hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c`. The important lines here are:

```
if (val == LOW) {
    *out &= ~bit;
} else {
    *out |= bit;
}
```

As you can see, it checks, if the given value (from the parameter) is equal to `LOW` and if so will set the corresponding pin to `0`. In every other case it will set the pin to `1`. The definition of `LOW` can be found in `arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h`:

```
#define HIGH 0x1
#define LOW  0x0
```

So the code checks, if the value is equal to `0` and sets the pin also to `0`. Every other value will result in a `1` (meaning `HIGH`). Also have a look at the definition of `digitalWrite()`:

```
void digitalWrite(uint8_t pin, uint8_t val)
```

The value is an unsigned type, so every signed type will be casted to an unsigned type. A negative number would result in a positive number inside the function.

Comment: Just nitpicking: Also `False` and anything other, which evaluates as 0, works here :) (And it is common to use boolean variables/expression as the val)